# Java - Passing 2D array to function

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|             | herndon | fairfax | baltimore | centerville |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   herndon   |    0    |    50   |    100    |     20      |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   fairfax   |   50    |    0    |    70     |     110     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  baltimore  |   100   |    70   |     0     |     200     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| centerville |   20    |    110  |    200    |      0      |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Java - Passing 2D array to function

1) defining a 2D array for distance and populate it -> done ( Its shown in program )

2) defining a city array -> done  ( Its shown in program )

3) ask the user for  soure and destination of the city :

e.g.

Enter from city:
 Enter To city:

Lets use JOptionPane and Error handling function when user enters cityNames.

4)call function" findDistance "and passsing array of citynames ,array of distances to this function.

5) call function " display" distance <- showing the distances of those cities that was entered by user .

problems i am having :

a)  passing arrays of citynames and array  of distance to findDistance function

(followup #4)

b) passing the argumants to function display.
(followup #5)

---

here is what i did so Far !

```
package test;


class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int distances[][] = {{0, 50, 100, 20}, {50, 0, 70, 110}, {100, 70, 0, 200}, {20, 110, 200, 0}}; // step 1
        String CityNames[] = {"herndon", "fairfax", "baltimore", "centerville"};  // step 2
        findDistance(distances); // ->  a . 1st problem , i am having problem to pass citynames and distances to this function.
        // display  ()     // -> b .  2nd problem i am having : i have a  issue to pass the arguments to this function to Display Distances between 2 cities .
    public static void findDistance(String[] names, int[] dist, int[] src) {
        for(int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
            // i would like to use JOptioanPane function and error handling
            // instead of system.out.println.
            System.out.println("enter from city" + src[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < dist.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter from city" + dist[i]);
        }
        int i = 0;
        dist[i] = src[i];
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to edit your question to a) make it more readable, b) not just do a homework dump

Comment: thanks Dave ;) it is just a practice i need ti get comfortable with , seems not a lot of coders are good with 2D Arrays .

Comment: Your code is a bit of a mess. Try to reduce your problem. Forget the Java GUI for a minute and just make a function that accepts the appropriate arguments and then call the function with the appropriate arguments. Get that working, then you can go further and implement the rest of your project.

Comment: thanks Matt , i am newbie with site and 2D array, calling and passing what argument i have a issue with .

Comment: @Sammy, your code was not well formatted. I have formatted it, let me know if you are not happy with the changes. I also recommend you to forget the graphical part for now as Matt suggested.

Comment: @RootG , that is correct in beginning i confused myself with graphical part ,

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and the given code, I wrote the below class. I intentionally left method bodies empty so you'll need to figure out some details there yourself. If you can fill bodies of `findDistance` and `display` methods you can accomplish what you want.

```
package Test;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int distances[][] = {{0, 50, 100, 20}, {50, 0, 70, 110}, {100, 70, 0, 200}, {20, 110, 200, 0}};
        String CityNames[] = {"herndon", "fairfax", "baltimore", "centerville"};
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter from city:");
        String src = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter to city:");
        String dest = keyboard.nextLine();
        int distance = findDistance(CityNames, distances, src, dest);
        display(distance);
    }

    public static int findDistance(String[] CityNames, int[][] distances, String src, String dest) {
        // Find and return the distance between src and dest.
        return 0;
    }

    public static void display(int distance) {
        // Display the distance to user.
    }
}
```

Comment: thank Mr root , i will look into it and i ll be right back .

Comment: nice , that was nice good practical concept  you shared , let me see what i can do now  , much appreciated for sharing your thought on solving method problem i have  ..

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it helps. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: hi root , i still couldnt find proper code for it .

Comment: I am not sure this is homework or not. I need you to show some effort if you want more help. Can you at least fill `display` method? There should be a single line of code. If you can write that one, I will edit my answer to include more clue. You can leave your answer to the comment section.

Comment: public static void display(int [] distance) // yours doesn't have [] // if i write like yours i get error //The primitive type int of distance does not have a field length .
       
  // Display the distance to user.
            {
             for (int i = 0; i < distance.length; i++)  
             {
                 System.out.print(distance[i] );
             }
         }

Comment: int[] destination = new int[src.length];
     int j = 0;
     for(int i=src.length; i > 0 ; --i)
     {
      destination[j]=src[i-1];
      ++j;
     } // i know i am getting close :)

Comment: Why do you want to store the distance in an array? You want to find the distance between two cities, so there should be a single distance. For example, the distance from herndon to baltimore should be 100, right?

Comment: that is right , i will look into more example of this type of "getting length of dimensional array " and i will comeback with more update .

Comment: teşekkür ederim .

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;


import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int distances[][] = {{0, 50, 100, 20}, {50, 0, 70, 110}, {100, 70, 0, 200}, {20, 110, 200, 0}};
        String cityNames[] = {"herndon", "fairfax", "baltimore", "centerville"};

        int departureIndex = findCityIndex("departure", cityNames);
        int destinationIndex = findCityIndex("destination", cityNames);
        display(departureIndex, destinationIndex, distances);
    }




    private static int findCityIndex(String cityType, String[] cityNames) {

        boolean cityNotFound = true;
        int index = 0;

        while(cityNotFound)
        {
            String cityName= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter " + cityType + " city");

            for (int i = 0; i < cityNames.length; i++)
            {
                if (cityName.equalsIgnoreCase(cityNames[i]))
                {
                    index = i;
                    cityNotFound = false;
                }

            }
            if (cityNotFound)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid city name. Please reenter.");
        }
        return index;
    }



    private static void display(int departureIndex, int destinationIndex, int[][] distances) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Distance is " + distances[departureIndex][destinationIndex]);
    }


}`enter code here`
```